# laravel eloquent not saving all the model parameters in the table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Model:

```
protected $table = 'citas_odontologicas';
protected $fillable = ['fecha','hora', 'procedimiento_id', 'paciente_id'];
```

Migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('citas_odontologicas', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string('fecha');
        $table->string('hora');
        $table->bigInteger('procedimiento_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('procedimiento_id')->references('id')->on('procedimientos');
        $table->bigInteger('paciente_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('paciente_id')->references('id')->on('pacientes');
    });
}
```

Controller:

```
public function agendarCita($fecha, $hora, $procedimiento, $paciente)
{
    $citaOdontologica = new CitaOdontologica($fecha, $hora, $procedimiento, $paciente);
    $citaOdontologica->save();
    dd($citaOdontologica);
}
```

Error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'fecha' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `citas_odontologicas` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2020-01-25 20:01:22, 2020-01-25 20:01:22))

Comment: Please, paste `CitaOdontologica` constructor code.

Comment: `function __construct($fecha, $hora, $procedimiento, $paciente)
    {
        $this->fecha         = $fecha;
        $this->hora          = $hora;
        $this->procedimiento = $procedimiento;
        $this->paciente      = $paciente;
    }`

Comment: `CitaOdontologica::create(['fetcha'=>$fecha, 'hora'=>$hora...]);` make an associative array and pass it to the `create` method. Or `$obj = new CitaOdontologica(); $obj->fill(['fetcha'=>$fecha, 'hora'=>$hora...])`

Comment: @Yeyez take a look at relations fields, looks like you forgot about `_id` suffix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel Model provides static API for creating objects. If you want to use `new ClassName()` notation, you have to override your model constructor. 
Remember about `_id` suffix for your relation fields (if you did not change it).

But i suggest to use `Model::create()` and `Model::make()` methods, like this:

```
$citaOdontologica = CitaOdontologica::make([
  'fecha' => $fecha, 
  'hora' => $hora, 
  'procedimiento_id' => $procedimiento, 
  'paciente_id' => $paciente
]);
$citaOdontologica->save();
```

or even simplier:

```
$citaOdontologica = CitaOdontologica::create([
  'fecha' => $fecha, 
  'hora' => $hora, 
  'procedimiento_id' => $procedimiento, 
  'paciente_id' => $paciente
]);
```

Comment: thanks, now it works. I had to delete my constructor, but that's not a problem because the values ​​are assigned anyway with the create or make methods.